# Align first letter and last letter of menu to left and right container border

Tags: wordpress, flexbox, elementor

I'm relatively new to Wordpress/Elementor world so I have to search for help.

I need to align the navigation menu that need to have the first letter of the first menu item sticked to the left border of the container and the last letter of the last menu item sticked to the right border of the container.
I need to do that in order to align the navigation menu to the image that is present below it.

In this moment what I have achive using margin is this, but with larger screen the aligment is not mantained anymore.

[image]

I tried with the align the first element to the left and the right elemento to the right using justify-content for these elements but this brings to have too much space between the first item and the second one, and the second-last and the last one, as you can see here:

[image]

Due to my low experience with css I'm stucked, and I don't know if I have to use another kind of container layout or something else.

Thank you in avdance for any help and I'll be happy to share some other information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

With flex you can use `justify-content: space-between` to distribute items as you asked.
[here you can find a very good guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you DaFois for the help. I tried with the solution you are proposing but it seems to align all the items as I set justify-content: left.

Comment: @FilippoLeoncini check the width of the parent container